# How to refactor code duplication inside static class?

Tags: c#, mysql, sockets, lua, redis

Below is a section of code that is part of a static class that is giving me trouble refactoring. I've spent a few weeks thinking about ways of approaching this but have been unsuccessful thus far.

Some context - this is part of a TCP Server I'm working on. The TCP Server behaves similar to the websocket specification - when a new client connects, all the management of the client socket is abstracted away, and instead simple callbacks are exposed which can be registered to subscribers.

ie. OnReceived, OnConnect, OnDisconnect, OnSend

This way I can have another class subscribe to the behaviors required from the socket client and keep the responsibilities of managing the socket and business logic separate. Whenever the client socket receives data, it reads the entire data block and then raises the 'OnReceived' callback method, passing in the received data.

The purpose of all of this is to read various requests from a Lua client and perform the appropriate action. Some actions will go to a MySQL Database (via calling stored procedure and passing the request data as arguments to the sproc). There is also the added flexibility of being able to send more than a single dataset in the request, meaning fewer request/responses need to be sent between client and server.

This has been great for many months and has made it very easy to maintain and change the business code without needing to worry about breaking the socket behavior. If I needed to change a stored procedure in a database, it only required updating the database and the Lua client code, as the TCP Server does not care about these implementation details.

However, now there is a new requirement which is to support both MySQL and Redis, and for the TCP Server to be able to direct the request to either of these sources in a flexible way.

The **first issue** of duplication is the **ProtocolResponseSingleData** and **ProtocolResponseMultiData** structs - these structures are almost identical, except for the 'Data' property. I need to be able to return either a single data set, or a collection of data sets. Both of these classes are serialized into a JSON string. This has caused duplication with ***SendToDBSingleData*** and ***SendToDBMultiData*** methods.

```c#
struct ProtocolResponseMultiData
{
    public string Action;
    public bool Result;
    public string Error;
    public List<List<object>> Data;
}

struct ProtocolResponseSingleData
{
    public string Action;
    public bool Result;
    public string Error;
    public List<object> Data;
}
```

The **second issue** is there are 4 methods which are very similar to each other in ways - SendToMySQLDBSingleData, SendToMySQLDBMultiData, SendToRedisDBSingleData, SendToRedisDBMultiData. I just can't seem to figure out how to collapse these down to 1 or 2 methods at most.

The **third issue** is this class is all static methods - the socket client exposes callbacks, but it is not aware of any particular instance of an object, hence the callbacks need to be declared static. This makes it difficult to apply things like Strategy and Factory patterns to simplify the design.

Is there any hope for me?

```c#
public static void OnReceived(object sender, IPCReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            LogToFile(e.data, ((SocketClient)(sender)).LogFile);
            Console.WriteLine("Received data from client (" + ((SocketClient)(sender)).Address + ")");

            dynamic j = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(e.data);

            // Verify the request format is valid
            if (j["Action"] != null && j["BulkQuery"] != null && j["Data"] != null && j["Destination"] != null)
            {
                ProtocolRequest request = new ProtocolRequest
                {
                    Action = j["Action"],
                    Destination = j["Destination"],
                    IPAddress = ((SocketClient)(sender)).Address,
                    LogPath = ((SocketClient)(sender)).LogFile
                };
                bool isBulkQuery = j["BulkQuery"];
                string jsonResp = "";
                if (isBulkQuery)
                {
                    ProtocolResponseMultiData resp = SendToDBMultiData(request, ref j);
                    jsonResp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resp);
                }
                else
                {
                    ProtocolResponseSingleData resp = SendToDBSingleData(request, ref j);
                    jsonResp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resp);
                }            
                ((SocketClient)(sender)).Write(jsonResp);
            }
            else
            {
                // send malformed request response
                string jsonResponse = "{ \"Action\" : " + j["Action"] + ", \"Result\" : false, \"Error\" : \"Malformed Request Received\", \"Data\" : null }";
                ((SocketClient)(sender)).Write(jsonResponse);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception encountered during OnReceived handler: " + ex.Message);
            LogToFile("Exception encountered during OnReceived handler: " + ex.Message, ((SocketClient)(sender)).LogFile);
            string jsonResponse = "{ \"Action\" : \"UNKNOWN\", \"Result\" : false, \"Error\" : \"Malformed JSON Request Received\", \"Data\" : null }";
            ((SocketClient)(sender)).Write(jsonResponse);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }

    public static ProtocolResponseSingleData SendToDBSingleData(ProtocolRequest request, ref dynamic j)
    {
        if (request.Destination == "MYSQL")
        {
            return SendToMySQLDBSingleData(request, ref j);
        }
        else if (request.Destination == "REDIS")
        {
            return SendToRedisDBSingleData(request, ref j);
        }
        else
        {
            ProtocolResponseSingleData response = new ProtocolResponseSingleData
            {
                Action = request.Action,
                Error = "Invalid Destination specified - must be either 'REDIS' or 'MYSQL'",
                Data = null,
                Result = false
            };
            return response;
        }
    }

    public static ProtocolResponseMultiData SendToDBMultiData(ProtocolRequest request, ref dynamic j)
    {
        if (request.Destination == "MYSQL")
        {
            return SendToMySQLDBMultiData(request, ref j);
        }
        else if (request.Destination == "REDIS")
        {
            return SendToRedisDBMultiData(request, ref j);
        }
        else
        {
            ProtocolResponseMultiData response = new ProtocolResponseMultiData
            {
                Action = request.Action,
                Error = "Invalid Destination specified - must be either 'REDIS' or 'MYSQL'",
                Data = null,
                Result = false
            };
            return response;
        }
    }

    private static ProtocolResponseSingleData SendToMySQLDBSingleData(ProtocolRequest request, ref dynamic j)
    {
        // serialize a new json string for just the data by itself
        string jdataString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(j["Data"]);
        // now deserialize this string into a list of dictionaries for parsing
        Dictionary<string, object> dataDictionary = null;

        if (((JToken)j["Data"]).Type == JTokenType.Object)
            dataDictionary = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jdataString);
        else
            dataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        ProtocolResponseSingleData result = new ProtocolResponseSingleData
        {
            Action = request.Action,
            Error = "",
            Data = new List<object>(),
            Result = false
        };

        // special scenario - because we cant get the ip address of the game server from DCS, we'll get it from the socket sender object
        // and specially insert it as a parameter into the data dictionary
        // the other special scenario is the server description request can supply - this can contain harmful html, so we must sanitize the input
        if (request.Action == ACTION_GET_SERVERID)
        {
            dataDictionary.Add("IP", request.IPAddress);
            if (dataDictionary.ContainsKey("Description"))
            {
                try
                {
                    string html = Convert.ToString(dataDictionary["Description"]);
                    html = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(html);
                    dataDictionary["Description"] = SanitizeHTML(html);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogToFile("Error sanitizing ServerDescription html string (Action: " + request.Action + ") - " + ex.Message, request.LogPath);
                    result.Error = "Error sanitizing ServerDescription html string (Action: " + request.Action + ") - " + ex.Message;
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }    

        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection _conn = null;
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader rdr = null;

        try
        {
            _conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(Config.MySQLDBConnect);
            _conn.Open();
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(request.Action)
            {
                Connection = _conn,
                CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };
            foreach (var d in dataDictionary)
            {
                if (d.Value.GetType() == typeof(Int64) && (Int64)d.Value == LUANULL)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(d.Key, null);
                else
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(d.Key, d.Value);
            }
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    result.Data.Add(rdr[i]);
                }
            }

            rdr.Close();
            _conn.Close();
            result.Result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogToFile("Error executing query against MySQL (Action: " + request.Action + ") - " + ex.Message, request.LogPath);
            result.Error = "Error executing query against MySQL (Action: " + request.Action + ") - " + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (_conn != null)
                if (_conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open || _conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Connecting)
                    _conn.Close();

            if (rdr != null)
                if (!rdr.IsClosed)
                    rdr.Close();
        }

        return result;

    }

    private static ProtocolResponseMultiData SendToMySQLDBMultiData(ProtocolRequest request, ref dynamic j)
    {

        // serialize a new json string for just the data by itself
        string jdataString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(j["Data"]);
        // now deserialize this string into a list of dictionaries for parsing
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> dataDictionary =
            Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(jdataString);

        ProtocolResponseMultiData result = new ProtocolResponseMultiData
        {
            Action = request.Action,
            Error = "",
            Data = new List<List<object>>(),
            Result = false
        };

        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection _conn = null;
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader rdr = null;

        try
        {
            foreach (var d in dataDictionary)
            {
                _conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(Config.MySQLDBConnect);
                _conn.Open();
                MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(request.Action)
                {
                    Connection = _conn,
                    CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };
                foreach (var kv in d)
                {
                    if (kv.Value.GetType() == typeof(Int64) && (Int64)kv.Value == LUANULL)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kv.Key, null);
                    else
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kv.Key, kv.Value);
                }
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (rdr.Read())
                {
                    List<object> result_set = new List<object>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        result_set.Add(rdr[i]);
                    }
                    result.Data.Add(result_set);
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Error += "No Results Returned\n";
                }
                rdr.Close();
                _conn.Close();
            }
            result.Result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogToFile("Error executing query against MySQL (Action: " + request.Action + ") - " + ex.Message, request.LogPath);
            result.Error = "Error executing query against MySQL (Action: " + request.Action + ") - " + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (_conn != null)
                if (_conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open || _conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Connecting)
                    _conn.Close();

            if (rdr != null)
                if (!rdr.IsClosed)
                    rdr.Close();
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static ProtocolResponseSingleData SendToRedisDBSingleData(ProtocolRequest request, ref dynamic j)
    {
        // Serialize the JSON Data property into its own JSON String
        string jdataString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(j["Data"]);

        // now deserialize this string into a list of dictionaries for parsing
        Dictionary<string, object> dataDictionary = null;

        if (((JToken)j["Data"]).Type == JTokenType.Object)
            dataDictionary = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jdataString);
        else
            dataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        ProtocolResponseSingleData result = new ProtocolResponseSingleData
        {
            Action = request.Action,
            Error = "",
            Data = new List<object>(),
            Result = false
        };

        if (!RedisConnection.IsConnected)
        {
            LogToFile("Connection to Redis Closed - Attempting to reopen...", request.LogPath);
            try
            {
                RedisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(Config.RedisDBConnect);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogToFile("Error connecting to Redis - lost connection (" + ex.Message + ")", request.LogPath);
                result.Error = "Error connecting to Redis - lost connection (" + ex.Message + ")";
                return result;
            }
        }

        try
        {
            string serverid = Convert.ToString(dataDictionary["ServerID"]);
            string rediskey = Config.RedisActionKeys[request.Action];

            if (serverid == null)
            {
                result.Error = "Error executing query against Redis (Action: " + request.Action + ") - " + "'ServerID' not found in Data request";
                return result;
            }

            if (rediskey == null)
            {
                result.Error = "Error executing query against Redis - Action: '" + request.Action + "' not found in server configuration - please check action message or server configuration.";
                return result;
            }

            IDatabase db = RedisConnection.GetDatabase();
            string k = rediskey + ":" + serverid;
            if (!db.StringSet(k, jdataString))
            {
                result.Error = "Failed to Set Key in Redis (Key: '" + k + "')";
            }
            else
            {
                result.Data.Add(1);
                result.Result = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogToFile("Error executing query against Redis (Action: " + request.Action + ") - " + ex.Message, request.LogPath);
            result.Error = "Error executing query against Redis (Action: " + request.Action + ") - " + ex.Message;
        }         

        return result;
    }

    private static ProtocolResponseMultiData SendToRedisDBMultiData(ProtocolRequest request, ref dynamic j)
    {
        // serialize a new json string for just the data by itself
        string jdataString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(j["Data"]);
        // now deserialize this string into a list of dictionaries for parsing
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> dataDictionary =
            Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(jdataString);

        ProtocolResponseMultiData result = new ProtocolResponseMultiData
        {
            Action = request.Action,
            Error = "",
            Data = new List<List<object>>(),
            Result = false
        };

        if (!RedisConnection.IsConnected)
        {
            LogToFile("Connection to Redis Closed - Attempting to reopen...", request.LogPath);
            try
            {
                RedisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(Config.RedisDBConnect);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogToFile("Error connecting to Redis - lost connection (" + ex.Message + ")", request.LogPath);
                result.Error = "Error connecting to Redis - lost connection (" + ex.Message + ")";
                return result;
            }
        }

        try
        {
            int id = 0;
            foreach (Dictionary<string, object> x in dataDictionary)
            {
                id += 1;
                string serverid = Convert.ToString(x["ServerID"]);
                string rediskey = Config.RedisActionKeys[request.Action];

                if (serverid == null)
                {
                    result.Error = "Error executing query against Redis (Action: " + request.Action + ") - " + "'ServerID' not found in Data request";
                    return result;
                }

                if (rediskey == null)
                {
                    result.Error = "Error executing query against Redis - Action: '" + request.Action + "' not found in server configuration - please check action message or server configuration.";
                    return result;
                }

                IDatabase db = RedisConnection.GetDatabase();
                string k = rediskey + ":" + serverid + ":" + id;
                string jdatastring = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
                if (!db.StringSet(k, jdatastring))
                {
                    result.Error = "Failed to Set Key in Redis (Key: '" + k + "')";
                    result.Result = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    List<object> res = new List<object>
                    {
                        k
                    };
                    result.Data.Add(res);
                    result.Result = true;
                }
            }    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogToFile("Error executing query against Redis (Action: " + request.Action + ") - " + ex.Message, request.LogPath);
            result.Error = "Error executing query against Redis (Action: " + request.Action + ") - " + ex.Message;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Is there really such a big difference between `ProtocolResponseSingleData` and a `ProtocolResponseMultiData` where `Data` only contains **one** item? Also, usually, when working with different db types, I'd expect some kind of connection factory where you give the type and it returns the right `IDbConnection` instance. Off of that, you can then create an `IDbCommand` and Parameters and all that good stuff.

Comment: @Corak how would you abstract Redis and MySQL to a common interface? In Redis, you would not be able to do cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue, because there is no such thing as a stored procedure, much less arguments.

Comment: See [DbProviderFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory) for more information.

Comment: `AddWithValue` is not really recommended anyway. I don't know about Redis, but if the command object implements `IDbCommand`, you can (and should) use the [CreateParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.idbcommand.createparameter.aspx) method. Set the name and value separately and don't forget to actually add the paramterer to the `command.Parameters` collection.

Comment: Okay, apparently, Redis doesn't work like that. So scratch that. -- Still, at least the two different response types (and with that, the two methods to get them per db type) seem unnecessary. -- Also, the methods seem to do a lot. How about cutting them up into smaller pieces to see, where they do basically the same (maybe with different types, but the same algorithm) and try to generalize those parts (maybe with generics)?

Comment: @Corak I definitely want to remove SendToDBSingleData and SendToDBMultiData, but I don't know how to collapse the return to a single type. I suppose Data could be made type object, but then each operation to Add to list involves casting the struct member which seems hacky. I also tried experimenting with Generics, but you can't overload a Generic on return type alone, so I'm stuck.

Comment: Again, what is the fundamental difference between a separate structure for single data and just (re-)using the structure for multi data but only having *one* item in `Data`? If you *have* to distinguish between an actual single data request and a real multi data request, that just so happens to return one item, then you could work with a boolean parameter and a corresponding Property in the response structure. Something like `IsSingleData`.